# Yii 2 Gridview sorting header- add custom parameter in the url

Tags: gridview, yii2, datagridviewcolumn, yii2-grid

When I click on the column header of Grid view, it is getting sorted, and in the URL sort parameter is gettting passed like `page/index?id=12&sort=column1`. I want to add another parameter while sorting like this `page/index?id=12&sort=column1&custom_id=2`.

Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it in your DataProvider using sort params like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    // ...
    'sort' => [
        'params' => ['custom_id' => 2]
    ]
]);
```

Note that according to  [this official documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-sort#$params-detail) if you set params explicitly - sort links won't have request's context GET params.

So you if you want your filter to persist you should merge $_GET array with your custom params injected to the link.

The example with merged $_GET:

```
$contextParams = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParams();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    // ...
    'sort' => [
        'params' => array_merge($contextParams, ['custom_id' => 2])
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!